# Change pchart separtor

Tags: php, pchart

I am working on an old system using pchart.

Now data is getting loaded into a big table. I managed to remove the seperator there so 4.000 is now shown as 4000.

I do experience a problem with the charts itself. The chart is based on the value above. But someone. The chart places a comma(,) in between the numbers. The chart ratio between the different bars is correct.

But inside the chart, it shows 4,000. This will confuse people when reading the chart. So i need to get rid of the comma there.

Is there anyone with any knowledge of pchart? I tried to look in theirs documention. But i can't find anything there.